# JavaFX: use a TableView as a calendar and fill it with events

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, calendar, tableview

I'm trying to make a calendar like application with fills a week schedule with lectures.

This is the code for the Lecture class:

```
public class Lecture {

    private final String course;

    private final int day;

    private final int duration;

    private final int studentId;

    private final int teacherId;

    private final int locationId;

    private final int firstBlock;

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public int getTeacherId() {
        return teacherId;
    }

    public int getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public int getFirstBlock() {
        return firstBlock;
    }

    public Lecture(String course, int day, int duration, int studentId, int teacherId, int locationId, int firstBlock){
        this.course = course;
        this.day = day;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.teacherId = teacherId;
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.firstBlock = firstBlock;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(course == null){
            return "(empty)";
        } else {
            return course;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the day and firstblock values the lecture gets placed in my TableView. Right now I made a custom row class which handles all this and fills the rows in my TableView. The result looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use a CellFactory to place the lectures on the right place? (maybe create labels with the name of the lecture, and empty labels if there isn't a lecture).

I also want to add a contextmenu that pops up when you right click a course or an empty cell to have to possibility to add or remove a course, which I need the cellfactory for I think. 
Note that it has to be possible to have more than one lecture in a cell.

Edit: Would it be possible to use different lists to fill different columns? for example a list that has all lectures for a monday?

Comment: If the rows correspond to times, the type for the `TableView` needs to be a type representing the different times. Then you would have a `TableColumn` for each day, with a `cellValueFactory` that returns the lecture corresponding to that day and time.

Comment: Firstblock is an int and corresponds to the right time. So should I use int as my TableView type?

Comment: You could (at least, an `Integer`), as long as you have a way to get a lecture given an `Integer` and a day.

Comment: So filter a list of lectures where the day equals an integer corresponding with the day, and the firstblock equals an integer corresponding with the hour?

Comment: Not sure I understand that.

Comment: I guess I would first question whether `TableView` is the right thing here, and whether it might be better just to use a `GridPane`. I also don't really understand why you are using primitive types for everything. Why is `day` an `int`, instead of a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)? Why is `duration` an `int`, instead of a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), etc?

Comment: I'm getting the lectures from a sqlite database. The lecture table has the same properties as the class that I've created to use them to fill up the tableview. I don't really understand what you mean "the type for the TableView needs to be a type representing the different times".

Comment: If I use a cellvaluefactory to fill a column, is it possible to bind the row number to the firstblockvalue of a lecture?

Comment: Each row in the table represents a time of day. So the table's backing list will be a list of values representing times of day, and the table's type will be whatever type you use for those values. (The obvious choice would be a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), so your table will be a `TableView<LocalTime>`.) There's no reason for the Java property types to be the same as the database types (and it's not really clear that an `int` is the best representation for a time of day in either case).

Comment: And, yes, a cell value factory is an arbitrary function, so of course you can retrieve any value you need.

Comment: But if a lecture should be placed in the third row, because its time matches the time indicated most left of the table, how can I tell the cellvaluefactory that it should be placed there? (so if the lecture has a firstblock of 3)

Comment: The cell value factory receives a parameter representing the row. Probably you need to look at a basic tutorial on `TableView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it :)